# Importing CSV without headers into D3 - data with both numbers and strings

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm working on a visualization where I need to import some csv data. Let's say the csv file looks something like this:

```
1,4,abc
2,7,def
3,5,ghi
...
```

The csv file does not have a header, so doing a search I have some code that looks like this:

```
d3.text("data.csv", function(text) {
    input = d3.csv.parseRows(text).map(function(row) {
        return row.map(function(value) {
            return +value;
        });
    });
    // do stuff here
});
```

This works great for data that contains only numbers, but my data has both numbers and strings. How can I modify this code so that only certain columns of data that I choose are turned into numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the index of the element in the `map` function to see whether it should be converted to a number:

```
 input = d3.csv.parseRows(text).map(function(row) {
    return row.map(function(value, index) {
        if(index == 2) {
            return value;
        } else {
            return +value;
        }
    });
});
```

This will only work for your specific case though.